# Page Requires Multi Part, and presentation part Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am trying to post a page to OneNote from the Microsoft Graph API, and when I enter in the section id that the page needs in order to post it throws me an error that states:

> Page create requests require the content to be multipart, with a presentation part.

My Request header looks like this:

```html
<!-- MyPartBoundary198374 -->
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type:text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A page with <i>rendered</i> images and an <b>attached</b> file</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2015-07-22T09:00:00-08:00" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here's an image from an online source:</p>
    <img src="http://..." alt="an image on the page" width="500" />
    <p>Here's an image uploaded as binary data:</p>
    <img src="name:imageBlock1" alt="an image on the page" width="300" />
    <p>Here's a file attachment:</p>
    <object data-attachment="FileName.pdf" data="name:fileBlock1" type="application/pdf" />
  </body>
</html>

<!-- MyPartBoundary198374 -->
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="imageBlock1"
Content-Type:image/jpeg

<!--  ... binary image data ...    -->

<!-- MyPartBoundary198374 -->
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="fileBlock1"
Content-Type:application/pdf

<!-- ... binary file data ... -->

<!-- MyPartBoundary198374 -->
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the initial request:

```html
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{id}/pages
Content-length: 312
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MyPartBoundary198374
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That solved my issue, could you also shed some light on the error Invalid entity ID?

Comment: Getting issue "The multi-part payload was malformed" using above code.